# How to use the camera API and set the picture to the canvas tag

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, phonegap-build

I am needing to write html code that uses the camera API in phonegap and sets the image to a defined canvas.  I found some code online that should work (also includes a watermark), but it does not return anything to the canvas.  Can someone tell me what I am missing?  I am new to html and javascript and just trying to figure out how this particular part works before I expand it to include other images to superimpose over the top of the picture taken from the camera.

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-    1.3.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

var canvas;
var watermark;

document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);  

function onDeviceReady() {
    canvasDOM = $("myCanvas")[0];
    canvas = canvasDOM.getContext("2d");

    watermark = new Image();
    watermark.src = "q1.jpg";    
} 

function cybershot() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(camSuccess, camError, {quality: 75, targetWidth: 400,     targetHeight: 400, destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI});
}

function camError(e) {
    console.log("Camera Error");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
}


function camSuccess(picuri) {
    console.log("Camera Success");

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = picuri;

    img.onload = function(e) {
        canvas.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        canvas.drawImage(watermark, canvasDOM.width-watermark.width, canvasDOM.height - watermark.height);
    }  
} </script>


<style>
#myCanvas {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
</style>


</head>
<body>
<h1>Watermark Camera</h1>


<button onclick="cybershot();">Capture Photo</button> <br>


<p>Canvas:</p>"

<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

If your code doesn't NEED a canvas, you can use a simple and clean method outlined in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2uvC6/2/):

```
function onSuccess(imageData) {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}
```

Alternatively, if you do require use of the canvas please refer to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JgRp5/1/) which shows that you can then take a programmatic image element and draw that to the canvas:

```
function onSuccess(imageData) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    image.onload = function () {
        var height = 100;
        var width = 100;
        context.drawImage(image, width, height);
    }
}
```

Let me know how you get on with that :)

Comment: If this was the answer to your problem, please mark it as such to help others in the future